# Java Stream Api Reverse Data Structure and Normalize Variables

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a `Home` class. There is an array of this class, I have to convert this data structure as `Map<AddressList, Number>` with java stream api. `Number` value will repeat for each address in same `Home` object. How can i do it? Thanks.

```
class Home {
    private Long number;
    private List<String> addressList;
    // getters, setters, constructor
}

class AnotherClass {
    List<Home> homeList = ....;

    // do something here and result
    Map<String, Long> barcodeNumberMap = ...;
}
```

---

SOLUTION

Thanks for your replies. Last code;

```
public void test() {
    List<Home> homeList = new ArrayList<>();
    Home h = new Home();
    List<String> barcode1List = new ArrayList<String>();
    barcode1List.add("b11");
    barcode1List.add("b12");
    h.setBarcodeList(barcode1List);
    h.setNumber(100L);

    Home h2 = new Home();
    List<String> barcode2List = new ArrayList<String>();
    barcode2List.add("b21");
    barcode2List.add("b22");
    h2.setBarcodeList(barcode2List);
    h2.setNumber(200L);

    homeList.add(h);
    homeList.add(h2);

    Map<String, Long> resultMap = homeList.stream()
        .flatMap(home -> home.getBarcodeList().stream()
            .map(addr -> new SimpleEntry<String, Long>(addr, home.getNumber())))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(SimpleEntry::getKey, SimpleEntry::getValue));

    System.out.println(resultMap);

    }
```

and Output:

> {b21=100, b12=200, b11=200, b22=100}

Comment: What `Map`? A `Map<Home, Long>` or a `Map<Long, List<Home>>` or anything else?

Comment: 51 secs late :( i've updated the question

Comment: Please provide input data and what output do you expect.

Comment: So you basically want to convert one `Home` to several pairs `<String, Long>` that contentually represent something like `<address, number>`, don't you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having:

```
List<Home> homeList = ....;
... your work ...
Map<String, Long> barcodeNumberMap = ...;
```

Then the *first* question should be how to fill the final map.
This is done with a `.collect(Collectors.toMap(keyGetter, valueGetter))`.

```
Map<String, Long> result =
    some obj stream of string and long
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(obj::getString, obj::getLong);
```

Then the `homeList` of Home: a long and many Strings, must be flattened.
Which basicall would flatten 10 Homes with each 20 Strings to 200 pairs of long and String. It probably may be assumed that every String value is unique.

A `Stream<Pair<String, long>>` would be done as

```
homeList.stream()
    .flatMap(home ->
         home.addressList.stream()
                          .map(addr -> Pair<String, Long>(addr, list.number)));
```

were one works for inner Home to the outside: a Home can be turned into a `Stream<Pair<String, Long>>` and flatMap then flattens the multiple streams.

As this seems home work, I stop here.